# Request user input of X/Y positions for turtle circle program

Tags: python

Here is my program:

```
from turtle import *
xpos=0
ypos=0
radius = 35
while radius > .1:
    pu()
    goto (xpos, ypos)
    pd()
    circle(radius)
    ypos = ypos + (radius*2)
    radius = radius - 5
```

I would like to somehow ASK the user to input x and y positions, and also request radius and shrink value. The program should then carry out the process that was keyed in by the user (depending on the integers they used) Is this possible?

I'm guessing it's something along the lines of int(input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `input` to do this. I didn't handle converting to ints and / or checking that they are indeed integer inputs. I leave this to you. Hint: `isdigit()` if you want to check for integer input.

`input` is python3 `raw_input` for python2

```
from turtle import *
....
    xpos = input("Enter the x position:")
    ypos = input("Enter the y position:")
    radius = input("Enter the radius:")
    shrink = input("Enter the shrink value")
    #convert above to int's, or turn into a function.
    ....
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply! I have changed my code to this but I am not getting past the input screen (Code crashes)

from turtle import *
xpos = input("Enter the x position:")
ypos = input("Enter the y position:")
radius = input("Enter the radius:")
shrink = input("Enter the shrink value")
    #convert above to int's, or turn into a function.
pu()
goto (xpos, ypos)
pd()
circle(radius)
ypos = ypos + (radius*2)
radius = radius - 5

Comment: Thank you again Pyth! Very sorry to ask so much, but I am getting a new error now! Here ismy code

from turtle import *
xpos = input(int("Enter the x position:"))
ypos = input(int("Enter the y position:"))
radius = input(int("Enter the radius:"))
shrink = input(int("Enter the shrink value"))
    #convert above to int's, or turn into a function.
pu()
goto (xpos, ypos)
pd()
circle(radius)
ypos = ypos + (radius*2)
radius = radius - 5

And here is the error
line 2, in <module>
    xpos = input(int("Enter the x position:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Enter the x position:'

Comment: You're converting to an int inside the `input` you want to convert outside of the input as you see in the other answer. I didn't write my answer this way bc if you did not put an integer in the conversion would fail with the error you see because your trying to convert a string to an integer. Hence, the bit about `isdigit()` before conversion if you did indeed want to check for these cases. If your on Python 3.x you should use `input` and if on Python 2 you should use `raw_input`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `raw_input`:

```
# use input if using python3
x_pos = int(raw_input("Insert x pos: "))
y_pos = int(raw_input("Insert y pos: "))
radius = int(raw_input("Insert radius: "))
shrink = int(raw_input("Insert shrink value: "))

print "x: {} y: {} radius: {} shrink: {}".format(x_pos, y_pos, radius, shrink)
```

Example on the command line:

```
% python request_input.py
Insert x pos: 4
Insert y pos: 5
Insert radius: 1
Insert shrink value: 2
x: 4 y: 5 radius: 1 shrink: 2
```